# How to display list item name instead of title of ModalDialogPopup confirmation box?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I created modalDialogPopup confirmation box with sharpoint object model. I want to display list item name instead of please confirm(title). See following code:

```
var options = {
    html: cloneModalContent, // ID of the HTML tag or HTML content to be displayed in modal dialog
    width: 375,
    height: 150,
    title: "Please Confirm",
    dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseDialog, // custom callback function
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true
   };

 SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Having the item just before show the modal dialog you need only to set the title in this way

```
var options = {
    ...,
    title: item.Title,
    ...
};
```

**[UPDATE 1]**

Try with this if doesn't work

```
//Using the DialogOptions class.
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

options.title = "My Dialog Title";
options.width = 400;
options.height = 600;
options.url = "/_layouts/DialogPage.aspx";

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Comment: why? did u get a error?

Comment: Its showing title as 'Dialog' .see my entire code here.. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93568/unable-to-execute-succeeded-failed-functions-after-modaldialogpopups-clos

Comment: @praveen.ji take a look on the update

Comment: oh my requirement is different .. When click on Display Form's  button it will show modal dialog and must show this dialog title as current list item title.